# Suppose $\#N = 5$. If $f: G \to \mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z}$ is a surjective homomorphism, what are the possible orders for the group $G$?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group with precisely one non-trivial proper normal subgroup $N$. Suppose $\#N = 5$. If $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z}$ is a surjective homomorphism, what are the possible orders for the group $G$?

So far I have the following: Since $f$ is surjective, we can use Homomorphism Theorem telling us $$G/\operatorname{Ker}(f) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z} $$ Where $\operatorname{Ker}(f) $ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Then, since N is the only proper normal subgroup we get (not sure about this step)
$$ G/N \cong \mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z} $$
and hence
$$ \#(G/N) = \frac{\#G}{\#N} = \frac{\#G}{5} = \# \mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z} = 6$$
So $\#G = 5 \times 6 = 30$? Is this the correct approach?

Comment: You need to show that $Ker(f)$ is $N$. If it weren't, then either $f$ is the zero morphism, which isn't surjective, or $f$ is an isomorphism and $G$ has order $6$, but then it doesn't have a subgroup of order $5$. Therefore $Ker(f)=N$ necessarily and your reasoning is true

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you Evariste